# How to populate columns in a table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to create a simple table using JavaScript based on an array with nested objects, which should have only two columns. In the first cell of the first column of the table, the Processor header is specified, after which the corresponding processor models are written to the lower cells. In the first cell of the second column, the Processor frequency header is indicated, after which the frequencies are written to the lower cells. I was able to generate code for this task, but it doesn't work correctly. Instead of writing keys to column cells after the first iteration, for some reason, it takes into account unnecessary objects. That's why you get an undefined value in the table headers and a re-duplication. Please tell me how to solve this problem.

```js
let processorFrequency = [
    {
        titleOne : 'Processor', values : [
            {name : '80386LC (1988г.)'},
            {name : '80486DX4 (1994г.)'},
            {name : 'Pentium MMX (1997г.)'},
            {name : 'Pentium II (1998г.)'},
            {name : 'Pentium III (1999г.)'},
            {name : 'Pentium IV'},
            {name : 'Athlon-Athlon XP'},
            {name : 'Athlon 64'},

        ]
    },
    {
        titleTwo : 'Processor frequency', values : [
            {name : '33-60'},
            {name : '80-133'},
            {name : '160-233'},
            {name : '260-550'},
            {name : '300-1400'},
            {name : '1600-3800'},
            {name : '1400-3200'},
            {name : '2600-3800'},
        ]
},
]



function Test(){
    let table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < processorFrequency.length; i++) {
        var pf = processorFrequency[i];
        let tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
        let tdOne = document.createElement('td');
        let tdTwo = document.createElement('td');
        let txtOne = document.createTextNode(pf.titleOne);
        let txtTwo = document.createTextNode(pf.titleTwo);
        
        tdOne.className = 'head';
        tdTwo.className = 'head';

        tdOne.appendChild(txtOne);
        tdTwo.appendChild(txtTwo);

        tableRow.appendChild(tdOne);
        tableRow.appendChild(tdTwo);
        table.appendChild(tableRow);

        var values = pf.values;
        for (let j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
            let value = values[j];
            let tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
            let td = document.createElement('td');
            let txt = document.createTextNode(value.name);
            td.appendChild(txt);
            tableRow.appendChild(td);
            table.appendChild(tableRow);
        }
    }
} 

Test();
```

```css
table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table><!-- Contents will be created via JavaScript -->
</table>
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question, and the Stack Snippet I added to it, to add the HTML to the snippet so that we have a [mre] and can see what is happening.

Comment: Note that there is no one element of `processorFrequency` that has both `titleOne` and `titleTwo` and therefore the code which looks for both on the same element will have one as undefined in each iteration.

Comment: If you are in control of the data I would rearrange it to be an array of objects like `{ processor: '80386LC (1988г.)', frequency: '33-60' }` so each object represents a processor and its frequency range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loops were confused as to where it was in the data structure.

Since `<table>` elements are constructed row-by-row, the simplest way is to add row elements in the outer loop:

```js
let processorFrequency = [
    {
        title : 'Processor', values : [
            {name : '80386LC (1988г.)'},
            {name : '80486DX4 (1994г.)'},
            {name : 'Pentium MMX (1997г.)'},
            {name : 'Pentium II (1998г.)'},
            {name : 'Pentium III (1999г.)'},
            {name : 'Pentium IV'},
            {name : 'Athlon-Athlon XP'},
            {name : 'Athlon 64'},

        ]
    },
    {
        title : 'Processor frequency', values : [
            {name : '33-60'},
            {name : '80-133'},
            {name : '160-233'},
            {name : '260-550'},
            {name : '300-1400'},
            {name : '1600-3800'},
            {name : '1400-3200'},
            {name : '2600-3800'},
        ]
},
]

function Test() {
    let table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
    // Add title row
    let titleRow = document.createElement('tr');
    table.appendChild(titleRow);
    for (let i = 0; i < processorFrequency.length; i++) {
        var columnData = processorFrequency[i];
        let titleCell = document.createElement('td');
        titleCell.className = 'head';
        titleCell.innerText = columnData.title;
        titleRow.appendChild(titleCell);
    }

    // Add data rows
    for (let rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < processorFrequency[0].values.length; rowIdx++) {
        let dataRow = document.createElement('tr');
        table.appendChild(dataRow);
        for (let i = 0; i < processorFrequency.length; i++) {
            var columnData = processorFrequency[i];
            let dataCell = document.createElement('td');
            if (columnData.values[rowIdx]) {
                dataCell.innerText = columnData.values[rowIdx].name;
            }

            dataRow.appendChild(dataCell);
        }
    }
}

Test();
```

```css
table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table><!-- Contents will be created via JavaScript -->
</table>
```

It might make the code simpler if you organized the data by row:

```js
let processorFrequencyRows = [
    ['Processor',                      'Processor frequency'],
    ['80386LC (1988г.)',               '33-60'],
    ['80486DX4 (1994г.)',              '80-133'],
    ['Pentium MMX (1997г.)',           '160-233'],
    ['Pentium II (1998г.)',            '260-550'],
    ['Pentium III (1999г.)',           '300-1400'],
    ['Pentium IV',                     '1600-3800'],
    ['Athlon-Athlon XP',               '1400-3200'],
    ['Athlon 64',                      '2600-3800'],
];

function Test() {
    let table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
    processorFrequencyRows.forEach((rowData) => {
        let row = document.createElement('tr');
        table.appendChild(row);
        rowData.forEach((cellText) => {
            let cell = document.createElement('td');
            cell.innerText = cellText;
            row.appendChild(cell);
        });
    });
}

Test();
```

```css
table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table><!-- Contents will be created via JavaScript -->
</table>
```

Comment: It's just great! Yes, I was thinking about simplifying the array by passing nested arrays to it, but the point is to make a table based on nested objects with pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the issue is that you are creating a new row for each processor AND frequency value, which results in extra rows being added to the table. The correct way should be create a single row for each processor, with two cells (one for the processor model and one for the processor frequency):

```
let processorFrequency = [
    {
        titleOne: 'Processor', values: [
            { name: '80386LC (1988г.)' },
            { name: '80486DX4 (1994г.)' },
            { name: 'Pentium MMX (1997г.)' },
            { name: 'Pentium II (1998г.)' },
            { name: 'Pentium III (1999г.)' },
            { name: 'Pentium IV' },
            { name: 'Athlon-Athlon XP' },
            { name: 'Athlon 64' },
        ]
    },
    {
        titleTwo: 'Processor frequency', values: [
            { name: '33-60' },
            { name: '80-133' },
            { name: '160-233' },
            { name: '260-550' },
            { name: '300-1400' },
            { name: '1600-3800' },
            { name: '1400-3200' },
            { name: '2600-3800' },
        ]
    },
];

function Test() {
    let table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

    for (let i = 0; i < processorFrequency[0].values.length; i++) {
        let tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
        
        // Processor Name Cell
        let tdOne = document.createElement('td');
        let txtOne = document.createTextNode(processorFrequency[0].values[i].name);
        tdOne.appendChild(txtOne);
        tableRow.appendChild(tdOne);

        // Processor Frequency Cell
        let tdTwo = document.createElement('td');
        let txtTwo = document.createTextNode(processorFrequency[1].values[i].name);
        tdTwo.appendChild(txtTwo);
        tableRow.appendChild(tdTwo);

        table.appendChild(tableRow);
    }
}

Test();
```

Comment: the answer is correct.. I suggest you to make it a live snippet so that it can be easily run and verified without further efforts

Comment: Yes, that's what you need. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

to populate table with columns based on array with nested object , where each object represents processor details , you can follow these steps :

1. create table element in your HTML file with the appropriate headers
2. write a javascript code to iterate over the array , extract  the processor models and frequencies , and populate the table cells accordingly